# Why same algorithm's runtime differs every time I rerun the program? Can someone explain me java runtime architecture?

Tags: java, runtime

I am measuring Factorial's recursive algorithm's runtime programmatically [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM2TN.png). Each time I rerun the program I get different runtime results, first run was the biggest one in time intervals. Why this happens? I moved from some C# experience to java and that was not case in C#.

Time differs from 0.2 to 0.009 seconds on Windows

public class Main {
static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Instant startInstant = Instant.now();

            BigInteger factResult = BigInteger.valueOf(algorithm1(30));
            System.out.println(factResult);

            Instant endInstant = Instant.now();
            Duration algorithDuration = Duration.between(startInstant, endInstant);

            BigDecimal algorithmTime = BigDecimal.valueOf(algorithDuration.toMillis());
            System.out.println("" + algorithmTime.divide((BigDecimal.valueOf(1000))));
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

private static int algorithm1(int factorial) {
    if (factorial == 1) {
        sb.append(1);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return 1;
    } else {
        sb.append(factorial + " * ");
    }
    return factorial * algorithm1(factorial - 1);
}
```

}

Comment: do not post picture, copy-paste the code to the question, specify runtime environment (hardware, OS, etc)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: could you add code with your question,  and expected output and actual output that you are getting

Comment: The chances are good that you're trying to measure 7mS intervals with a clock that ticks every 10mS.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to SO. This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Good luck.